# Oracle 10g - Insert in to Temporary Table - Record count mismatch between select and insert

Tags: oracle, insert, temp-tables

We are trying insert records from a select query in to temporary table, some of the records is missing in the temporary table.  The select statement is having multiple joins and union all which it little complex query.
In simple terms the script contains 2 part
1st Part
   Insert in to temporary table
2nd part
   Select query with multiple joins, inline sub queries, unions and group by classes and conditions

Eg.
   If we execute select statement alone it returns some count for example => 60000
   After inserting into the temp table, in temp table the count is around 42000
why is the difference?

**Also, we have some other observation.  It only happens in its 2nd execution and not its first run.  Hope there might be some cache problem**

---

We got a solution, once we clear session cache (checkpoint, flush shared_pool and buffer_cache) it works fine for Re_Run.

### However, we do not know is this solution ok? and how clearing cache works in the background and failed insert. If it is true, something wrong configuration setup, i guess.

The code looks like
sql = "insert in to temptable select x,y,z,.... from xxx,abc,pqr..where...."; (logial but not real is very complex around 700 lines with multiple joins, inline sub queries, group by etc. )
stmt = conn.createStatement();
rCount= stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
**Actual issue is
rCount = xxxx = Count(temptable) < count(select x,y,z,.... from xxx,abc,pqr..where....)**
why this diffference ? some records populated in the select but not inserted in to temp table

Anyone can explain?

thank you in advance for your efforts and help.

Shiva.

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make sense.  If the query returns 60,000 rows and you are doing a straight `INSERT ... SELECT`, the `INSERT` will insert 60,000 rows.  If you are seeing something different, either the queries aren't identical, the data isn't identical (potentially one or the other is running against some uncommitted changes), or you have encountered an Oracle bug that requires a patch.  An Oracle bug is, by far, the least probable of the options.

Comment: if i understood your statements correctly, it is simple bulk inserts... insert in to temp table select * from xxx.  also, there is no commit in between.  The problem is all the records populated by the select statement are not inserted in to temp table.  some records are not inserted.

Comment: It is not possible for a SQL statement to partially succeed (again, short of the very unlikely event that you happen to have run across a serious Oracle bug).  I would strongly wager that every row the `SELECT` statement returns when run in the session you run it in and when run at the time you run it gets inserted into the table.

Comment: Even, we also did not believe that.  We are wondering.  In TOAD, we tested however at times it happens.  In application, in jar file, after "insert in to temp select * from xxx" we take the i. record count of temp table and ii. record count of "select * from xxx" separately but both doesn't match.  Match only at 1st time.

Comment: On the second run does the SELECT statement (without the INSERT) continue to return 60,000 rows?

Comment: yep, result set of select query is consistent since, the 2nd count is taken directly from the select statement

Comment: What do you mean about the first and second run? Did you delete all records from temp table between them? Did you do the second run with the same data or different ones? Please explain more detail.

Comment: no. since, it is temp table will be removed after commit.  We tested in the application.  again we execute the batch is called 2nd run.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion the join should be Full Outer Join, so that records from both tables will come in the result though they do not match. Please check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join

Comment: the select query looks fine.  there is no issue.  however, the issue on insert in to temp table.  What i am trying to say is, all the records populated from the select statement are not inserted.  Means Some records are not inserted in to temporary table

Answer (score 0):

**We got a solution, once we clear session cache (checkpoint, flush shared_pool and buffer_cache) it works fine for Re_Run.** 
However, we do not is this solution ok? and how clearing cache works in the background and failed insert. If it is true, something wrong configuration setup, i guess.

Anyone can explain?